# PHP GET JSON using cURL, sorting returned array

Tags: php, json, curl

I am returning JSON from a web service using PHP. I am able to get the JSON, decode it, and see the results. However, I need to be able to sort the array by a particular value. I currently have:

```
// JSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'https://*******/maincategories';

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting JSON result string

$data = json_decode($result);

ksort($data, "Total");

print_r($data);
```

The `print_r($data);` prints this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Goal] => 10000000 [Name] => Rental [Total] => 500000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Goal] => 8000000 [Name] => National Sales [Total] => 750000 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Goal] => 120000000 [Name] => Vendor Leasing [Total] => 500000 ) )
```

I was attempting to use ksort and sort the array by ascending order via the `Total` key. How can I sort this array so that the object with the highest total is first, and the rest follow in ascending order?

Comment: ksort() doesn't work on multidimensional arrays, which is basically what you've got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->Total - $b->Total;
});
```

Note that if you want an associative array instead of objects from `json_decode`, then use `json_decode(..., true)`

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of objects. As such, you will need to define you own custom sort rules.  You should use `usort()` for this. Perhaps something like this:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    if ((int)$a->Total > (int)$b->Total)) {
        return 1;
    } else if ((int)$a->Total < (int)$b->Total)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```